# Is there a way to refresh just the javascript include while doing development?

Tags: javascript

While doing development on a .js file I'd like to just refresh that file instead of the entire page to save time. Anyone know of any techniques for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a function to create a new script element. It appends an incremented integer to make the URL of the script unique (as Kon suggested) in order to force a download.

```
var index = 0;
function refreshScript (src) {
  var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
  scriptElement.src = src + '?' + index++;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
}
```

Then in the Firebug console, you can call it as:

```
refreshScript('my_script.js');
```

You'll need to make sure that the index itself is not part of the script being reloaded!

The Firebug Net panel will help you see whether the script is being downloaded. The response status should be "200 OK" and not "304 Not Modified. Also, you should see the index appended in the query string.

The Firebug HTML panel will help you see whether the script element was appended to the head element.

UPDATE:

Here is a version that uses a timestamp instead of an index variable. As @davyM suggests, it is a more flexible approach:

```
function refreshScript (src) {
  var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
  scriptElement.src = src + '?' + (new Date).getTime();
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
}
```

Alexei's points are also well-stated.

Comment: i would use the time (new Date().getTime()) instead of an index (removes the need of a global variable). If you refresh the same script alot, you could even create a bookmarklet.

Comment: +1. Please beware that reloading script will not update evry object already loaded. You may run into interesting issues where old versions of functions are used (i.e. as callbacks/closures/exisitng objects).

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly the kind of thing I needed. I created a temp button on my page to fire it. Will be a huge time saver, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Firebug for this purpose.
See this video, it helped me a lot.

http://encosia.com/2009/09/21/updated-see-how-i-used-firebug-to-learn-jquery/

Comment: Not ideal if I'm working with tweaks across multiple functions in a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the unfortunate case of client-side/browser caching of your .js file, then you can simply version your .js file.  You can:

- Rename the .js file itself (not preferred)
- Update the include line to reference yourfile.js?1, yourfile.js?2, etc..  Thus forcing the browser to request the latest version from the server. (preferred)

Comment: Nope, it's not a cache issue. I want to refresh the .js *without* refreshing the entire page. Kind of like how you can quickly edit CSS via Firebug without having to refresh the page each time to test your results. Not exactly like that, because I do want to save the changes in the .js file -- but the point is I don't want to refresh the entire page.

Comment: Outside of standard debugging practices (e.g. evaluating expressions, checking values, etc.) I don't know how you can do what you're trying to do.  Unfortunately, reloading the full page is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to refresh the web page to see edits to your JavaScript take place. There is no way that I know of to edit JavaScript in "real-time" and see those edits effect without a refresh.

You can use Firebug to insert *new* JavaScript, and make real-time changes to DOM objects; but you cannot edit JavaScript that has already been run.

Comment: I know you can edit css and html via Firebug, but I don't see how .js files are editable?

Comment: click on "Console" and paste your js code on right side panel.

Comment: @Susan Sorry, that was a poor word choice; what I meant by that was you could use the Console tab to write your JS and have that show you changes in realtime. I edited my answer to be more specific.

Comment: Ok, so the jist I'm getting so far is "no, not possible that we know of". Adding js after via console is not ideal if I have a whole include of functions I'm editing; think it'd just be quicker to wait for the page refresh. I wonder if there's any ajaxy way of refreshing just a .js file?

Answer (score 0):

If you just fed up refilling the forms while developing just use form recover extensions like this one https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/